# Hibernate join two tables on non-unique column

Tags: hibernate, join, primary-key, unique

I have two tables

```
Appointment
{
   long appointment_id,
   String description,
   String usercode,

}

SecurityGroup
{
    long id,
    String usercode,
    String groupDn
}
```

The usercode is not primary key in both two tables. It is also not unique column on both two tables.

How to define the domain model if i only want to have one-to-many relationship from appointment to securityGroup?

Thanks

Comment: i believe you will need a foreign key in order to define a one to many relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key to defining table relationship's is primary key. No primary key's means no foreign key's , no JPA's. Better define primary key's and then define your relationships.